# Вставить \ перед "

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно вставить \ перед " в довольно большом объёме текста поэтому я хочу написать простенький скрипт на python,но я не знаю как это сделать. Пример : был текст `что-то""что-то`, а должен получиться `что-то\"\" что-то`

Comment: в примере ошибка и должно получиться 'что-то\"\"что-то'

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем именно Python, чем функция замены в любом текстовом редакторе не угодила?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К оригинальному тексту примените метод `replace()`:

```
text = 'яблоко""груша""апельсин""слива'
result = text.replace('""', '\\"')

# Тест
print(text)
print(result)
```

> ```
> яблоко""груша""апельсин""слива
> яблоко\"груша\"апельсин\"слива
> ```

- Первый параметр — часть текста, которую хотите заменить (`""`).
- Второй параметр — текст, на который вы хотите еe заменить (`\"`)
  (его нужно написать — между апострофами — как `\\"`, потому что `\"` Питон интерпретирует как один знак: кавычку (`"`)).